# How to set a width measurement to be the width of some string of text in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, width, textwidth

I have some code like this:

\setupfield[cloze][width=]

I need to set width to be the width of some text given to it, such as "hello this is some text" or even just "#1" if it is given a variable to put there.

I think there is a command "\settowidth" in regular LaTeX, but in ConTeXt I tried \setupfield[cloze][width=\settowidth{here is some text}] and it failed to compile throwing some strange error elsewhere in the document, so I suspect the {}'s aren't right.

Is there a way to set the width to the measurement of the width of some given string of text?

Comment: You're looking for the `\widthofstring{...}` command but be aware no formatting commands (e.g. `\bf`) are allowed in the argument.

Comment: Fantastic! That works perfectly.

Comment: Another option, it you want the width with formatting commands is to use something like `\scrachbox\hbox{ ... string ...} ` and then use `\the\wd\scracthbox`

Comment: @Aditya When you need formatting you can use the `\setwidthof` command, e.g. `\setwidthof \bf Bold text!\to \FormattedText` and the use `width=\FormattedText`.